# Inaccurate table numbering with LyX

Tags: tables, floats, lyx, longtable

I'm using LyX to create some tables, but the numbering is complete borked.

In the LyX window, the table numbers are accurate. However, when I render to a PDF, they are evens only: 2, 4, 6 etc.  (I'm sure I don't need to explain what even numbers are, but you get the point).

[image]

Delving into the source code generated:

```
\selectlanguage{english}%
~\foreignlanguage{british}{}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{raggedright}
\begin{longtable}[l]{|r|>{\raggedright}m{0.8\textwidth}|c|}
\hline 
\selectlanguage{british}%
No.\selectlanguage{english}%
 & \selectlanguage{british}%
Requirement\selectlanguage{english}%
 & \selectlanguage{british}%
Priority\selectlanguage{english}%
\tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{longtable}
\par\end{raggedright}

\selectlanguage{british}%
\caption{Test table}
\selectlanguage{english}%
\end{table}
```

This is a test table, hence no data. But, I did notice `\begin{table}` and `\begin{longtable}`.

Would I be correct in assuming this is the cause of the problem? If so, does any know how I can go about removing it?

N.b. I've been into the table settings and the `long table` checkbox is ticked but greyed out, so that's not much use.

Comment: The syntax should be something like `\begin{longtable}[l]{|r|>{\raggedright}m{0.8\textwidth}|c|}
\caption{Test table}\\hline(...contents...)\end{longtable}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated code is full of redundant (or even wrong) things. I don't understand why continuously switching between `english` and `british`, for instance: a document should use *one* English variety, either AmE or BrE.

Using `longtable` inside a `table` environment is completely useless. Just a `tabular` will do. And this is the cause of the wrong numbering, by the way.

The `raggedright` environment doesn't exist and using the environment form is bound to problems.

```
\begin{table}
\raggedright
\begin{tabular}[l]{|r|>{\raggedright}m{0.8\textwidth}|c|}
\hline 
No. & Requirement & Priority \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\caption{Test table}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer egreg. I guess this is a prime example why using straight latex would be better.